# PHP doesn't detect white space in string

Tags: php

I'm working on transferring data from one database to another. For this I have to map some values (string) to integers and this is where I run into a strange problem.

The string looks like this $string = "word anotherword"; so two words (or one space).
When I explode the string or count the amount of spaces it misses the white space. Why? I var_dumped the variable and it says it's a string.

Below is the code i'm using.

```
echo "<strong>Phases</strong>: ".$fases = mapPhase($lijst[DB_PREFIX.'projectPhase']);
```

The string that's being send to the function is for example "Design Concept". This calls the following function (where the spaces get ignored)

```
function mapPhase($phases){
    echo "Whitespace amount: ".substr_count($phases, ' ')."<br />";
}
```

For the example string given this function echoes 0. What's causing this and how can i fix it? The strangest thing is that for one instance the function worked perfectly.

Comment: Maybe it's a tab and not a space?

Comment: Er wait... is your function really supposed to just echo the output and return nothing?

Comment: works for me. You probably have string with Non-breaking space or another unprintable character.

Comment: @AlexHowansky No, I removed the non-essential stuff as this is the only thing that's important for the question.

Comment: are you sure that the space between the words is a space (e.g. ' '). because it could be a lot of things, that looks like a space in the browser, but is actually not. (for a rudementary list, see here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Comment: @alex Thanks! I had no idea characters like that showed up as spaces. After testing it the data apparently consists of spaces in some strings en \n-characters in others. If you add this as a new answer I'll select it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may well be that the alleged space in the string may not be a space as in ' ', but something similar, which gets rendered in the browser in the same way as ' ' would. (for a rudimentary list of possible characters: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Thus, checking what the whitespace exactly is may be the solution to that problem.

Answer (score 3):

More than one whitespaces (in HTML) are always converter into one whitespace. For example code indents.

If you want to print more than one, one by one use `&nbps;` instead.

```
function mapPhase($phases){
    echo 'Whitespace amount: '.substr_count($phases, '&nbsp;').'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are not even spaces. Try [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) for each symbol in your string.

ord(' ') is 32.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```